# Auto-rewriting remote WSDLs

Tags: mule

Mules pattern-based web-service-proxy configuration, (pattern:web-service-proxy) supports auto-rewriting remote WSDLs. But how exactly does this work?

A remote URL normally is normally buildt up according to such a pattern:

```
http://host1.domain.com:8080/ServicePath
```

In the examples i have seen, a host-name with a domain-part is auto-rewritten to just the hostname/machinename of the hosting server (without domain part), something like:

```
http://host2:8080/ServicePath
```

Does the 'auto-rewriting'-feature somehow support handling of the domain part of the host-name, or is this outside of the scope of this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `web-service-proxy` tries to rewrite the address using the address of outbound endpoint as the source and the address of the in-flight request as the destination. It also tries to deal with the rare case of WSDLs that contain localhost and replace them with `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`.

So if the proxy's WSDL is accessed with `http://host1.domain.com:8080/ServicePath?wsdl` and the remote web service address is `http://remote.acme.com/service`, the proxy will rewrite `http://remote.acme.com/service` found in the WSDL to `http://host1.domain.com:8080/ServicePath`.

But if the same service is accessed with `http://host1:8080/ServicePath?wsdl` then you will get `http://host1:8080/ServicePath` in the WSDL.

In summary: it's all based on the caller's URL, except if the WSDL contains `localhost` URLs (which should not be the case).